# Change the "What topics can I ask about here?" help center page

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-topic, help-center

This is about the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the site's help center.

Back in 2010, Robert Cartaino posted a Stack Exchange blog post titled [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). That post talks about how hard it is to have subjective questions, and outlines half a dozen guidelines that helps define a *good* subjective question. Since Worldbuilding is, by definition, a rather subjective site (few of our questions have hard answers that are either "right" or "wrong"; it's more of a continuum than a binary either/or situation), I propose that we add a link to that post to our help center article.

Currently, the help center article says, in part:

> Note that questions must be [specific](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [answerable](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific question-and-answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question.

How does the community feel about such a change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose that we change the relevant paragraph to:

> Note that questions must be [specific](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [answerable](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific question-and-answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question. Such questions may however be welcome in [Worldbuilding Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=worldbuilding.stackexchange.com). Also see [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for why this type of question is hard, and some guidelines on how to post *good* subjective questions which are less likely to end up being closed.

(Feel free to make minor adjustments to the phrasing here, but if you wish to state a difference of opinion, make that a separate answer so that community voting works!)